# How to pass data via segue from one View Controller to another with optionals

Tags: swift, macos, segue, swift3, nsstoryboard

I am trying to get my data to pass from one view to the next when I click on an NSCollectionViewItem.  When an item is clicked I simply want to pass some data to a new view for a more "detailed" view of each item.

I keep getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  I feel like I am missing a key step in the ProductDetail.swift file.  The error occurs at the bottom of ViewController.swift in my prepare() method.  The process on how to do this for OS X is completely different than iOS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var colView: NSCollectionView!

var productCategories: [ProductCategory]?

var productsArray: [ProductModel]?

var detailLabel: test1? 



override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 1025, height: 1200)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    getJSON()

}

func getJSON() {

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myurl.php")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode



        if (statusCode == 200) {

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.mutableContainers)

                self.productsArray = [ProductModel]()

                if let products = json as? [[String: Any]] {

                    for product in products {

                        let testproduct = ProductModel()

                        testproduct.product_name = product["product_name"] as? String
                        testproduct.product_price = product["product_price"] as? String
                        testproduct.product_image = product["product_image"] as? String



                        self.productsArray?.append(testproduct)



                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(){

                        self.colView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            }catch {

                print("Error parsing the JSON: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()

}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

}

extension ViewController: NSCollectionViewDataSource, NSCollectionViewDelegate{


func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return productsArray?.count ?? 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

    let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "test1", for: indexPath) as! test1

        item.buildProduct  = productsArray?[indexPath.item]

    return item
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {

    print("selected")

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProductDetail", sender: self)



}
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    if (segue.identifier == "showProductDetail") {

        if let detailVC = segue.destinationController as? ProductDetail {

        detailVC.testLabel.stringValue = (detailLabel?.label.stringValue)!

        }else{
            detailLabel?.label.stringValue = "failed"
        }


    }


}
}
```

**test1.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class test1: NSCollectionViewItem {

@IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: NSImageView!

var productItem: ProductModel?


var buildProduct: ProductModel? {

    didSet{

        label.stringValue = (buildProduct?.product_name)!
        label2.stringValue = (buildProduct?.product_price)!


        setupAppIconImage()
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func setupAppIconImage() {

    if let appIconImageURL = buildProduct?.product_image {
        let url = NSURL(string: appIconImageURL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL,completionHandler:{(data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            self.productImageView.image = NSImage(data: data!)

        }).resume()

    }

}
}
```

**ProductDetail.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ProductDetail: NSViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: NSTextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your `detailLabel` variable in `ViewController`? It is not initialized and hence it is nil. So your app is crashing.

Comment: Try to initialize it in your `didSelectItemAt` method with `let item = collectionView.item(at: indexPaths) as! test1
        detailLabel = item`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got an error saying "Cannot invoke 'item' with an argument list of type '(at: Set<IndexPath>)"

Comment: Try this: `let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.selectionIndexPaths.first
        let item = collectionView.item(at: selectedIndexPath!)
        detailLabel = item`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions but that still didnt work.  I am trying to go a different way now and I have gotten rid of the optional issue but I am still unsure how to pass the correct data over to the ProductDetail View Controller:  'if detailLabel != nil {
                
                detailVC?.testLabel.stringValue = (detailLabel?.buildProduct?.product_name)!
            }else {
                
                print ("failed")
            }
'   I keep coming back with "failed"

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't have the value you need to set the value for it before accessing it.

Comment: I see what you are saying i will keep trying out some more things but I think the issue I am having is that I am trying to pass data to a second view from my first view.  My first view is comprised of a NSCollectionView and each item of my collection view is created by my test1.siwft file representing a .xib file.

Comment: You are doing right thing passing data from one VC to another but when you have the data then only you can pass right? So when you select an item, you need capture that value so that you can pass, which you can do it in didselect as mentioned earlier

Comment: I took your advice and when I print out 'let testing = detailLabel?.label.stringValue
                
                print(testing)'  in my prepare method I get the correct result.  But then wehn i trie to assign it to my testLabel in my ProductDetail I come back to getting Optional nil errors again.  I have my statement unwrapped but it still throws the error.  How do I assign the value properly to my second view's Label now that I have captured the value.

Comment: That's great you are able to capture the value to be passed. Now check if your testLabel is hooked up properly in ProductDetail xib/storyboard whichever. And also make sure you have the segue defined in storyboard.

Comment: Yes they are both hooked up correctly.

Comment: Am I not unwrapping my values properly?  I keep getting this error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when trying to assign my values that I have captured to the ProductDetails testLabel

Comment: Try to print : print(detailLabel.label) and print(detailVC.testLabel) within your prepare method before assigning the value and Let me know what you get in console

Comment: print(detailLabel.label)  comes back with (<NSTextField: 0x6180001e2f00>)   and print(detailVC.testLabel) comes back with nil.

Comment: I would assume that my testLabel would be nil because it has nothing assigned to it.  Hence why I want to assign the value of my detailLabel to it.

Comment: No, you have not hooked up the `IBOutlet` for `detailVC.testLabel` and hence the object itself is `nil`. If you have a object then only you can assign a value. Please check your outlet in XIB if it has set or not.

Comment: I guess I am confused.  I have hooked up my outlet to my ProductDetail.swift file.  I am then accessing it through detailVC = segue.destinationController as? ProductDetail.  By creating this detailVC variable I thought I would have access to that testLabel which I seem to but the value never changes.  I can assign a variable to it but then it still never changes:  'var viaSegue = ""'   and then 'testLabel.stringValue = viaSegue'  I get rid of the error but then my second view comes back with nothing because it is loading the viaSegue variable instead of assigning it the detailLabel value.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out.  It was much simpler than I thought.  I needed to create a variable to hold the new data being passed in.  Thank you to Santosh for his help and guidance.

**ProductDetail.swift**

```
class ProductDetail: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: NSTextField!

var theBigPass = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    testLabel.stringValue = theBigPass

}

}
```

**ViewController.swift Segue Methods**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {

    print("selected")

    let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.selectionIndexPaths.first
    let item = collectionView.item(at: selectedIndexPath!)
    detailLabel = item as! test1?

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProductDetail", sender: self)


}

override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {



    if (segue.identifier == "showProductDetail") {


        if let detailVC = segue.destinationController as? ProductDetail {

            let passed = (detailLabel?.label.stringValue)!

            detailVC.theBigPass = passed


        }

    }
}
```